# Can I change a plist file in the NSBundle folder?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsbundle

Is it allowed to change a plist file in my Cocoa app's bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you shouldn't do that. Make a method that returns the contents of /your.plist if it exists and have it fall back to /your.plist if it doesn't. When modifying it, always save it to Documents.

Comment: It's better to save it somewhere in `~/Library`, such as `Application Support` (or the equivalent, for a sandboxed app)—applications shouldn't touch `~/Documents`.

Comment: Sorry, thought it was an iOS question for some reason, but the idea is the same. Copy the file over to some place you own if you need to modify it.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying the contents of your application bundle is generally a bad idea. For example, it can break your application's code signature.